# Resource name for Xterm's logging filename

Tags: xterm

Xterm supports the following command line option:

```
-lf filename                 logging filename
```

What is the name of the resource for this option in order to specify the filename in the `.Xdefaults` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the good old days I used the resource

```
XTerm*VT100.logFile
```

However, xterm is usually compiled without this feature nowadays, as a security precaution, so this may have no effect.

Comment: Do you know the syntax for the date pattern in the file name?

Comment: You should look at Thomas Dickey's answer. The date format is fixed.

Comment: I found it: https://github.com/ThomasDickey/xterm-snapshots/blob/9a635cf47ec0bdb3d9acd77f6af4f8e5a008d0a9/misc.c#L2008

Answer (score 1):

The place to look is in the [xterm manual](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#OPTIONS:-l), which says

```
   -l      Turn logging on, unless disabled by the logInhibit resource.

           Some versions of xterm may have logging enabled.  However,
           normally logging is not supported, due to security concerns in
           the early 1990s.  That was a problem in X11R4 xterm (1989)
           which was addressed by a patch to X11R5 late in 1993.  X11R6
           included these fixes.  The older version (when running with
           root privilege) would create the log-file using root privilege.
           The reason why xterm ran with root privileges was to open
           pseudo-terminals.  Those privileges are now needed only on very
           old systems: Unix98 pseudo-terminals made the BSD scheme
           unnecessary.

           Unless overridden by the -lf option or the logFile resource:

           o   The logfile is written to the directory from which xterm is
               invoked.

           o   The filename is generated, of the form

                   XtermLog.XXXXXX

               or

                   Xterm.log.hostname.yyyy.mm.dd.hh.mm.ss.XXXXXX

               depending on how xterm was built.
```

and (for people *building* xterm, e.g., for packaging) the [`INSTALL`](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/xterm-snapshots/blob/master/INSTALL#L456) file explains the relevant configure script option:

--enable-logging        enable logging

```
    Compile-in code that allows logging.

    Logging was disabled in X11R5 xterm because of security problems.
    They were addressed in X11R6, but the feature was not reinstated.
```

X11R6 was released 20 years ago, and it's rather unlikely that you are using the X11R5 version of xterm.

However... the manual page does not mention the related resources.  For that you have to read the source-code, starting with the [resource table](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/xterm-snapshots/blob/master/charproc.c#L539):

```
#ifdef ALLOWLOGGING
    Bres(XtNlogInhibit, XtCLogInhibit, misc.logInhibit, False),
    Bres(XtNlogging, XtCLogging, misc.log_on, False),
    Sres(XtNlogFile, XtCLogfile, screen.logfile, NULL),
#endif
```

That is, there are three related resources, [`logInhibit`](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:logInhibit), [logging](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:logging) and [`logFile`](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:logFile).  The last of those allows one to specify a name for the log file, which overrides the generated name.

I always have the feature compiled-in, for occasional testing.  The Debian package enables it, the Fedora package does not (some packagers read the instructions, some do not).

The *reason* why the feature is not turned on by default is for the same reason that *most* features are not turned on by default: it is not essential to using the program.  Most new features are added with a default "off" setting.  The most recent exception to that rule was in 2014, adding the `--disable-wide-attr` configure option.